# Linux distro that contains Windows fonts in default

Tags: fonts

I personally don't like Linux and Mac OS X fonts.

**They are too cartoonish and childish (fat, bold).**

So, I would like to find a Linux distribution that contains Windows fonts in default. I know it may not be legal, but I am sure such distros exist; or at least I hope ;).

I tried to install MS fonts on Ubunty and it's better. but still the fonts are not the same as on Windows.

The gnome interface don't bother me such. I am worried mostly about rendering in browsers in Ubuntu.

Do you know about such distribution that has all Windows fonts and renders pages in the firefox the same way as on windows?

Is KDE rendering better than Gnome rendering in browsers?

**UPDATE:**

Here is a comparison, so you see what I mean. The top picture is from Win 7 Firefox and the second from Ubuntu 13.04 Firefox browser.

You can clearly see that on Ubuntu the text under the title is deformed and not so high as it supposed to be on Wndows. How to fix that, so proportion of the fonts on Ubuntu are the same? I have installed the MS fonts on Ubuntu. But it is not helping.

[image]

Comment: I'm suppressing an angry rant here, instead I'll just point out that font is handled by X11, and every mainstream distro uses X11 right now.

Comment: @Wutaz Any idea about something other than X11 that I can try?

Comment: @Renan I think that this problem is not an "artificial" problem that is exclusive only for me. It's a real problem that I have experiencing and I would like to solve it. I have updated my question with a screenshot from `bild.de` website viewed by altest Firefox on WIn 7 and by latest Firefox on Ubuntu 13.04. You, can clearly see the deformed text under the title for the 2 posts. So, please consider to reopen this question. I really need to have the same font proportions in my Linux browser and Windows machine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You're not going to find "the" de-facto Windows font, Arial, packaged with a (mainstream) linux distribution because:

> Arial is a proprietary typeface

via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial).

Comment: So, none of the 2 or 3 hundred distribution contain Arial font? I know it's not legal. But I am skeptical that none of the distribution out there contain MS fonts. Anyway, thanks. I will wait for other answers a couple of hours though.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu and derivatives have the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package available for installation. It contains the Microsoft fonts:

```
Andale Mono
Arial Black
Arial (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Comic Sans MS (Bold)
Courier New (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Georgia (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Impact
Times New Roman (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Trebuchet (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Verdana (Bold, Italic, Bold Italic)
Webdings
```

along with a sexy ASCII EULA that you need to agree to. However, if you're not pleased with X font rendering, it probably won't help you much.

You might want to check that [your anti-aliasing](https://askubuntu.com/a/68029/1078) is set properly.

Comment: I have everything set like that (rgba...). It's not helping some fonts are deformed in Firefox and Chromium and make the design on some pages ugly.